# Uploading file using Post mehod to web service with XMLDocument as a parameter in C#

Tags: c#, web-services

I am new to web service. I want to send the XML file to the web method without adding reference to webservice class, using Post method but every time i am getting Error 500 
can any body help me?????

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASMX (.Net 2.0) services then you can change the webservice URL at runtime.
I don't find any other reason for not adding a Web service reference.

Also for **500 Internal Server Error** check whether you can access the web service.

This should solve your issue.